# Since when does Node.js offer ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

EcmaScript 6 has been published in 2015. In which version were ES6 classes introduced in Node.js? I couldn't find the related [github commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

I'd like to know which was the first Node.js version allowing to use the `class` keyword as syntactical sugar for prototypes.

Comment: http://node.green/

Comment: https://iojs.org/en/

Comment: node 6 have class keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Node v4.3.2

Was the first version to accept Class method according to http://node.green/

Comment: I downloaded `v4.0.0` and it already has class keyword...

Answer (score 0):

This is the last release I found which you can use for backwards compatibility testing: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.12.18/

```js
> class Test {}
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:44:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:117:23)
    at bound (domain.js:291:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:304:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```